# VBA grabbing unique attributes from a XML tree

Tags: xml, vba, xpath, msxml

Is there a way to use the .getAttribute method (or any other method) within VBA to select only the unique (non duplicated) attributes within a XMLDOMSelection object?

In other words, I have an XML doc that has the following:

```
<plants>
    <plant color="green" height="7">Apple</plant>
    <plant color="red" height="7">zztop</plant>
    <plant color="red" height="8">42</plant>
</plants>
```

I want to grab all plants that have unique values by color. So I want another output that says, here are all the unique colors - green and red.

As it is, I've been using a recursive cycle to extract all of the values (duplicated as well) and run the final through another function to remove duplicates. However, the problem with this is that it's too computationally expensive.

Please let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since VBA only supports XPath 1.0, you should be able to use this XPath 1.0 expression :

```
/plants/plant[not(@color = following-sibling::plant/@color)]/@color
```

The predicate being used above restricts the XPath to return only the last occurrence of the same `color` in case there are multiple of them. Notice that there is no need to climb up to the parent node of current `<plant>` node (using shortcut `..`) before calling `following-sibling::plant` because those `<plant>` nodes are at the same level already.

Comment: Nitpick: It's not *VBA* that supports XPath 1.0, it's MSXML2. VBA supports whatever the COM module that you use supports.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XPath 2.0:

`distinct-values(/plants/plant/@color)`

and XPath 1.0:

`/plants/plant[not(@color = ../following-sibling::plant/@color)]/@color`